# for comprehension with "case-like" type check

Tags: scala

The following piece of code is not compiling. Trying to perform a "case-like" type check for the items in `listOfSomething` (e.g. `case s:String => //dosomething`)

```
class A

class B extends A

class C extends A

val listOfSomething: List[A] = List.empty[A]
val result = for {
  s:B <- listOfSomething
} yield s
```

The error is more than obvious and the problem does lay on the fact that `A`s will also be cast to `B`s and this will fail.

```
Error:(41, 15) type mismatch;
found   : B => B
required: A => ?
s: B <- listOfSomething
```

My question is the following: Is my only option here doing something like the following?

```
val result = for {
  s <- listOfSomething if s.isInstanceOf[B]
} yield s
```

or do you see any other options like the more elegant "case-like" type check?

**EDIT**: I do not want to use `collect` since I want to include multiple entries in this for comprehension and I would have to create a deeply nested structure if I was to use `collect`s e.g.

```
val result = for {
  s:B <- listOfSomething
  other <- anotherList if s.foo == "foo" && s.bar == "bar"
  another <- yetAnotherList if other.x == "x" && other.y == "y"
  .... // goes on
} yield s
```

Comment: Why not using **case classes**? You then can `case B(blah) <- list`

Comment: This is  an old and known problem, the workaround can be found in the question I have suggested as a duplicate. If it works for you, you can confirm it as a duplicate.

Comment: Yes you're right. I do not really like the workaround tbh since it involves the introduction of another class but I guess it is is the only way.

Comment: The workaround is nice in that the workaround class is generic and can be used for all type pattern matching you do. You can include the class in some your utility library and reuse it whenever you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Scala 3](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/b4EX2kgbQUOxrTs2za9Wrw) try with parenthesis around `(s: B)` like so

```
for {
  (s: B) <- listOfSomething
} yield s
```

then it seems to desugar to

```
listOfSomething
  .withFilter { case (s: B) => true; case _ => false }
  .map({ case (s: B) => s })
```

Comment: This does not fix the problem. The type mismatch error persists.

Comment: It is good to know a future Scala 3 will lift the restriction, but as of now I am afraid it is not a practical solution for most purposes.